# How to store selenium screenshots when the test fails thru jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, screenshot

I want to store the screenshot for my Java and selenium tests on a shared drive.As the shared drive is not accessible by the Jenkins server the screenshots are not saved.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you already know how to create and store the build artifacts in Jenkins. In my experience I've also used a dedicated file server for such scenario - shared content between multiple servers. You can try this [Publish Over SSH Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin). It can send the screenshot files from your *\Workspace* over SSH (SFTP) and all you need is a dedicated Post-build action, which will be executed after your test run.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from publishing files through SSH plugin in jenkins, it is always a better practice to build a test report web page with the screenshot of the test. So it copies all the resources of the page while you publish the test report as HTML. Try [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) plugin for sending html report.

Answer (score 0):

The recommend method is to save your files through a Jenkins plugin.  I have faced several scenarios where process drops due to security and plugin issues. Try your best to use a Jenkins plugin and still you cannot, you can do the following.

Create a simple program which copy files (There are many sample sources available) and you can invoke it by a bat/shell script through Jenkins after the test execution.